# Error while running npm "prefix -g is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: node.js

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I am using windows 8.1 enterprise version,  and I have my files in appdata/npm still I am getting the above error. I installed the latest node version,i.e, v6.3.0 and I've even tried with the older version of node ,i.e, v4.4.7 and I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Mine also printed this issue.

> error file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;

seems I screwed up my comSpec in my environmental variables.
The ";" at the end of that line was causing the error.

Comment: In my case it was set to: %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe
Where %SystemRoot% was giving  C:\windows  with a small letter w in windows.

After I hard coded it to C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -> it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if still have the same the problem but recently I was experienced this annoying error and finished solving by modified the `npm.cmd` file found in nodejs installation folder. It seems the error occurs because a wrong use of apostrophes and double quotes when calling the `npm.cmd` file. By default the npm.cmd comes in this way:

`'CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g'`

You need to change that to

`"CALL ""%NODE_EXE%"" ""%NPM_CLI_JS%"" prefix -g"`

In that way the .cmd must be executed correctly, or at least work for me in Windows 10 OS.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This way you effectively prohibit the subcommand to execute, because it is treated as a literal string. It is the execution of the subcommand that somehow triggers this error (I'm not sure why, I have the same problem, while colleagues do not). This fix is equivalent to removing the forloop and subsequent if statement altogether.

Comment: Worked for me as well in windows 10. Much thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same issue. It was caused by the semi-colon of some environment variables.

If you are in Windows, first try to using the command SET, it will list out all your environment variables.

```
C:\Users>SET
```

Then, try to check all the variables carefully to see is there any semi-colon at the end of any variables. If there is any, delete the semi-colon.

In my case, previous

```
ComSpec=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;
```

So I delete the semi-colon of ComSpec and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me also worked deleting `;` from ComSpec environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue npm “prefix -g is not recognized as an internal or external command”
on window 8.It takes approx half of the day to solve.

> Actual problem is window Environment variable path.

Here are the some steps that I follow to solve the problem.

**1:** Firslty, I remove node and npm default path setup by the node while installation .
   **Example**: `*C:\Program Files\nodejs;* *C:\Users\{pcName}\AppData\Roaming\npm*`
    if node path is exist both:path and PATH variable remove the node and npm path.

**2:** Check the Every environment variable if anyone having npm or node path remove the node and npm path.
    In my case: **ComSpec=** having some path of nodejs 
    expample:
`ComSpec=C:\Users\{pcName}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angularCli****`
     I replaced the value of
`ComSpec=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`     (without semicolon) 

**3:** Add both nodejs and npm path in only system path or both path and PATH(if exist) variable:

````
path=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\{userName}\AppData\Roaming\npm```
````

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a custom shell configured in the `ComSpec` environment variable. Removing this fixed the problem.