# npm command return message -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit and install npm with Windows Installer from nodejs.org. Every time i enter npm command, it always showing this message:
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[Error while running npm “prefix -g is not recognized as an internal or external command”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277910/error-while-running-npm-prefix-g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external) not solving my problem

**node -v**

> v6.10.0

**npm -v**

> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not
> recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file.
>
> 3.10.10

**npm config get registry**

> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not
> recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file.
>
> https://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It solved now. it is not an error of nodejs PATH. But one of my environment variable named ComSpec has multiple value, it only allow one

Answer (score 1):

This error refers to your PATH variable not pointing to the right path of NodeJS. Double check your env. vars and check if it is set to the right path.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in nodejs. I have .env file on my project folder, but there isn't a var that pointing to nodejs path. Shoud i set them into my .env file?

Comment: I meant your windows environment variables. For the path go to "Windows Isntallation" : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_environment_setup.htm, for how to set paths in windows: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_environment_setup.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_environment_setup.htm) still getting the error, C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin is not exist in my directory

Comment: check X86 Program Files

Comment: Reinstall node.js

Comment: I've been several times to reinstall node.js, but still displays the same error message. i'm using this installer [https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.0/node-v6.10.0-x64.msi](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.0/node-v6.10.0-x64.msi)

Comment: When you install check the installation path

Comment: Still no luck. here is my nodejs configs and env. vars on my computer http://pastebin.com/bjARYBeW