# Nodejs and npm installation on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I know this question maybe looks like a stupid question, but I am new in using nodejs.

After I had installed the nodejs, I wrote this command to check it

**->node -v** 

 
the output was
 
**v10.3.0**

but when I wrote 
**->npm -v**

the output was 
**'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"  "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as internal or external command, 

operable program or batch file.


6.1.0**

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42667234/5331813) but it does not work for me.
And I uninstalled nodejs then I reinstalled it again.

I restarted the PC also, nothing happened.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: did you install nodejs globally?

Comment: Can you try with NVM https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: @iwayankit yes I installed it globally.

Comment: @SharathiRB Is it instead of npm ?

Comment: No, its node version manager it has capable of handling node basic installation issues include npm.

Comment: And moreover, direct node.js installation is not that much suggested. Always go with nvm which will help you to switch multiple node version on the same machine.

Comment: @sharathirB okay I will try it now

Comment: @sharathiRB it works now after using nvm.

Comment: Great. Let's play with nvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now after using nvm, from this [link](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)

As @Sharathi RB said in comments

It is node version manager it has capable of handling node basic installation issues include npm. 

And moreover, direct node.js installation is not that much suggested. Always go with nvm which will help you to switch multiple node version on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

In environment properties, in path variable just add  **C:\Program Files\nodejs**  and reopen CMD. It will work.