# I can't run npm or npx because of cli's mistake

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

When I try to run npm or npx in cmd/powershell，it tells me：

```
C:\Users\k6789>npm
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

But when I run this in powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\k6789> node -v
v19.1.0
```

And my environment variable `ComSpec` is `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508090/npm-command-return-message-g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comm) can't help me.

This is my `Path` variable：

```
C:\Python310\Scripts\;
C:\Python310\;
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
%IntelliJ IDEA%;
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs;
%NVM_HOME%;
%NVM_SYMLINK%;
```

This is my `C:\Program Files\nodejs`:

[image]

How to solve my problem? Or should I use `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v19.1.0\node.exe` rather than `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`?

Comment: Can you check if your Path variable is correctly set, and includes the folder where your npm and npx execs are present?

Comment: npm version is?