# prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When I am trying to use `npm install` command in cmd; I got following error:

> CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

Can anybody help me regarding this error?

Comment: What is the exact command you're typing into the console?

Comment: There is a similar question with some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508090/npm-command-return-message-g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comm

Comment: There is also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277910/error-while-running-npm-prefix-g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external

Have you seen / tried them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while running npm "prefix -g is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277910/error-while-running-npm-prefix-g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external)