# I keep getting this error after typing npm start into the terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-start

I keep getting these errors. Recently developed a simple web app and posted on my repository and kept getting these errors thereafter.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE – David 1 hour ago   
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Users'username'\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_'numbersandletters'\cmd\git.exe; C:\Program Files\nodejs   
npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Users'username'\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_'numbersandletters'\cmd\git.exe; C:\Program Files\nodejs   
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Users'username'\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_'numbersandletters'\cmd\git.exe; C:\Program Files\nodejs   
npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! robofriends@0.1.0 start: react-scripts start 
pm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Users'username'\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_'numbersandletters'\cmd\git.exe; C:\Program Files\nodejs ENOENT npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the robofriends@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-01-09T03_19_55_548Z-debug.log C:\Users\hp\Desktop\David\robofriends>
```

i kept getting erros even after deleting the node modules and package.json, i uninstalled node and installed again, ran npm innit to get my package.json and i got this error

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What are the errors? u didn't post them and also share your package.json

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow @David! Please add the code to the post, and not in the comments, which will allow initial readers to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

ENOENT means `no such file or directory`, meaning something being referenced by some process doesn't exist where the process thought it did, such as the node executable, cmd.exe, or the react-scripts executable in node_modules. In this case it seems to be a Windows-specific issue. Adding cmd.exe to your path may fix things. [See this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59053744/5774952).

Comment: kept getting erros even after deleting the node modules and package.json, i uninstalled node and installed again, ran npm innit to get my package.json and i got this error

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Can you take a look at this and see if that's the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277910/error-while-running-npm-prefix-g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external